# Receiving error when using Next generator extension in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I installed the next generator extension in Inkscape following directions of unzipping the file and placing it in the Extension file.

When I run it i receive this error `Cannot merge PDF files, please install Ghostscript (see https://ghostscript.com).`

I have Gohstscript installed with the path in place.

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue myself. I believe you're on Windows, like I am, as this solution may not work on other platforms.

The way to resolve it is to locate your Ghostscript executables (usually found in the `bin` directory of where you installed GS), duplicate the `gswin64.exe` file and rename the duplicate to `gs.exe`. Then, try again.

It's a bit crude, but it works.